# No boot device and file system not found in bios

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, boot-partition

Dell did a firmware update this morning on my xps running ubuntu and since then it hadn't been working properly so whilw trying to reinstall I ended up accidentally installing in legacy mode not uefi and now I'm missing boot options.

1) if I try to boot it goes to Dell SupportAssist scan and eventually just tells me No boot able devices found
2) Bios UEFI Add boot option says No File system found

I have a live usb for ubuntu available. When I try to install it only reads the USB itself and asks me to install on that 16gb drive. How to install ubuntu back on my ssd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu/Linux in legacy mode in a GPT drive is possible but requires an additional small unformatted partition. I'sure

1. you didn't change the drive from GPT to "msdos" (MBR) and
2. you didn't created the additional partition.

Anyway there's no point in using legacy.

Just reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Note that you didn't have to reinstall it but since you did using a wrong method, reinstalling again is now the most efficient use of your time.

What happened to you is typical when the UEFI firmware is upgraded, it looses the efi files information but it should be possible to boot Ubuntu as before by selecting a specific EFI file (still there in the EFI partition) and once booted run `sudo update-grub` to refresh the UEFI boot entries.